# Moving LiveMeeting admin functions to a different window

Tags: multiple-monitors, live-meeting

I run a user group, and often host LiveMeeting sessions. I use a projector, with a crowd watching.

How do I do the admin stuff (respond to Q&A, etc) on one window, and just have the video on the 'extended monitor'? I dont' want the people in the audience to see anything except the video feed, but I want to be able to watch questions come in, etc...

Note: I don't have a problem extending the screen across the two monitors - I already have different stuff showing on my screen compared to the projector. I just want a way to put the LM video on Monitor 2 (projector), and the LM controls on Monitor 1.

Comment: I deleted my answer until I found a better solution, though MaxiVista isn't a bad idea!

Comment: What version of LiveMeeting are you using?

Comment: 2007. Version: 8.0.6362.149

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... The menus can detach, and then be dragged to other monitors.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most practical solution but it does work for me.

- Instead of sharing a screen, upload the presentation file to Live Meeting
- Move the Live Meeting window to your primary monitor
- Set Powerpoint to show slide show in the additional monitor and the presenter view in primary, and go to slide show
- Move the Live Meeting window back to the second monitor, maximize share the uploaded file, and go to full screen mode. I will be over the slide show that is linked to your presenter view, so your presenter view does not command what people see in the Live Meeting, **which I found dramatically useful** instead of a disadvantage, because I can still use the presenter view to do a presentation from my home, move trough the slide show as I want while they see the the slide I want.
- Advance your Powerpoint as desired using the full screen buttons on the Live Meeting screen
- Keep using your PC as desired

Comment: I'll try this and see.